# How to get environment variable in a bat command in groovy file?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Here a make de environment variable:

```
environment {
    SERVICE_NAME = getServiceName()
}
```

This is the method:

```
def getServiceName() {
    String projectName = env.JOB_BASE_NAME
    print 'projectName '+projectName  +'\n'
    String[] projectParts = projectName.tokenize( '-' )
    String bian = projectParts[1]
    String name = projectParts[0]+'-'+projectParts[1]+'-'+projectParts[2]
    return name
}
```

And I need to take de SERVICE_NAME variable in the next bat command, but it give me an error:

```
bat '''
                copy "C:\\Users\\""\\.jenkins\\workspace\\'"%env.SERVICE_NAME%"'\\target\\newman\\V2\\report.html" "C:\\server\\test\\'"env.SERVICE_NAME"'\\report_%date:~6,4%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~0,2%_%time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,2%.html"
                copy "C:\\Users\\""\\.jenkins\\workspace\\'"%env.SERVICE_NAME%"'\\target\\newman\\V2\\report.json" "C:\\server\\test\\'"env.SERVICE_NAME"'\\report_%date:~6,4%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~0,2%_%time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,2%.json"
            '''
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I don’t think `env.` is recognized by batch commands as is. Either use `%SERVICE_NAME%` or `$env.SERVICE_NAME`, in both cases without the extra quotes surrounding it. The latter will allow Groovy to interpolate it rather than Windows command line.

Comment: try with bat ''' echo %SERVICE_NAME%''' from there we move forward.